# DNN 5.2.3 "GetPortalAliasByPortalID @PortalID=0" looping

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

After tracing the DB activity from a DNN 5.2.3 site I noticed that there are 15 calls to the "dbo.GetPortalAliasByPortalID @PortalID=0" sproc, all one after the other.

What is the reason for this? I am looking at performance problems and need to try and tie issues like these up.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this issue in 5.3. can you provide more info on how to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Thanks for attempting in Keivan. I'm logging into the home page of the site after restarting IIS (to clear cache etc.) as an administrator in 'View' mode.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of DNN are you running?

Comment: sorry I meant version number, 4.9.5, 5.2.1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is probably a quirk of DNN. The number of repeated queries is fewer as a User as opposed to an Administrator.